# Propel 1.6 How to autogenerate Base/Peer/Query model classes in symfony2

Tags: mysql, symfony, model, propel

I am a newbie Propel1.6 user and I would like to know the way to generate Base/Peer/Query classes in my model using commandline. How do I do that? or can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks alot

Comment: That a good thing if u show some effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive done it by running

```
app/console propel:build
```

to generate an sql file, then

```
app/console propel:model:build
```

to build the model classes (Base,Peer,Query) and

```
app/console propel:sql:insert --force
```

to generate the mysql tables